# What's wrong with this Latex equation? Missing $? and undefinded control sequence

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} % Farbunterstützung
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Mathe
\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Direkte Eingabe von Umlauten und anderen Diakritika
\usepackage{braket}

(-1)^p=(-1)^\{$P^{\prime}$\+$P^{\prime\prime}$\}
```

Comment: Welcome! You cannot have `(-1)^p=(-1)^` outside `math` mode. Try `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(-1)^p=(-1)^{P^{\prime}+P^{\prime\prime}}$
or
$(-1)^p=(-1)^{\{P^{\prime}+P^{\prime\prime}\}}$
\end{document}`.

Comment: You're also missing both a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}` directive.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you're looking for. (I would also argue that writing `'` is easier than `^{\prime}` -- and that writing `''` is a lot easier than `^{\prime\prime}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(-1)^p=(-1)^{(P'+P'')}$
\end{document}
```